Fabricjs won't initialize - Angular v18
As in the title, I have installed all required packages with no problems.
When I import fabric like so:
import  { fabric }  from 'fabric';

I get following command line error:

TS2305: Module '"fabric"' has no exported member 'fabric'.

I guess it might be issue with wrong import but I cannot find answer anywhere.

Are you using fabric v5 or v6?

@JSONDerulo yes, its v6. This line from below answer seem to do the trick.
import * as fabric from 'fabric';

You might be using V6 of fabric.js, go for the below import, as per the documentation.
import * as fabric from 'fabric'; // v6
import { fabric } from 'fabric'; // v5

You can also try to import the individual items using the below import.
import { Canvas, Rect } from 'fabric'; // browser
import { StaticCanvas, Rect } from 'fabric/node'; // node


Yep, the v6 line seem to do the trick tho if I just use this line:
"import { Canvas, Rect } from 'fabric';
I get following error:
"TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'fabric'."

do you by any chance know how I can apply local blur to the background image?
Just like i would add say circle but it would be a blur not color?

@dozobus Does this answer help you?

Looks like what I need but after I try to load image with this "fabric.Image.fromURL..."
I get this error: "TS2559: Type '(img: any) => void' has no properties in common with type 'LoadImageOptions'."
And when I do: "var img = new fabric.Image.fromURL..."
I get this:  "TS2350: Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword."

@dozobus if you could share a stackblitz where the error happens, I will check it in a new question please

I finally got the stackblitz but there I cannot got past building process, it throws multiple errors about missing files related to fabric package.
link @Naren Murali
